# sqlite vb.net multi insert in one command from datatable

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, datatable

I have this code, but it only inserts 7 records out of 54.
I am sure that the records are fine in the datatable.

```
Dim dt As DataTable
Dim sc As SQLiteCommand
Dim Script As String = Nothing
Dim Script2 As String = Nothing
Dim Script3 As String = Nothing
Script = "insert into paperdate(dtime,papernum,paperstat,user) select " & "'" & dt.Rows(0)(0) & "'" & " as " & "dtime" & "," & dt.Rows(0)(1) & " as " & "papernum" & "," & "'" & dt.Rows(0)(2) & "'" & " as " & "paperstat" & "," & "'" & dt.Rows(0)(3) & "'" & " as " & "user"
For i As Integer = 1 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
Script2 = " union select " & "'" & dt.Rows(i)(0) & "'" & "," & dt.Rows(i)(1) & "," & "'" & dt.Rows(i)(2) & "'" & "," & "'" & dt.Rows(i)(3) & "'"
Script3 = Script3 & Script2
Next
sc = New SQLiteCommand(Script & Script3, mycon)
sc.ExecuteNonQuery()
sc.Dispose()
```

I hope someone has the answer,
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that you have duplicate records in the second select. If that is the case, then the solution is to use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.

> A compound SELECT created using UNION ALL operator returns all the
>   rows from the SELECT to the left of the UNION ALL operator, and all
>   the rows from the SELECT to the right of it. The UNION operator works
>   the same way as UNION ALL, except that duplicate rows are removed from
>   the final result set.

Reference: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html

If that isn't it, then you might want to trace the SQL, and run the `SELECT` parts directly in the sqlite client.

**Update**

As per your comment, here is the change you would do to your code:

```
Script2 = " union select " & "'" & dt.Rows(i)(0) & "'" & "," & dt.Rows(i)(1) & "," & "'" & dt.Rows(i)(2) & "'" & "," & "'" & dt.Rows(i)(3) & "'"
```

becomes

```
Script2 = " union all select " & "'" & dt.Rows(i)(0) & "'" & "," & dt.Rows(i)(1) & "," & "'" & dt.Rows(i)(2) & "'" & "," & "'" & dt.Rows(i)(3) & "'"
```

Comment: Ok, yes, I have so many duplicate records, because it doesn't have a primary key, can you update my code of what are you trying to say, just wanna be sure.  thanks

Comment: @XenKid: sure, I augmented my answer as you asked.